BPB_FATSz16/32 Values in the FAT32, 16 and 12 Filesystems
I'm currently writing a FAT formatting application and the FAT docs state the boot sector variable BPB_FATSz16 and BPB_FATSz32 but does not have any guidance on what appropriate values are for this variable. The variable is only described as the number of sectors that the File Allocation Table should occupy.
How would I go about deriving an appropriate value for this field?

You set the field to the number of sectors you need for the file allocation table, whih is affected by the size of the disk you are formating.

http://elm-chan.org/docs/fat_e.html

You can take inspiration from dosfstools.

"does not have any guidance on what appropriate values are for this variable" is mostly incorrect. While BPB_FATSz16 and BPB_FATSz32 are only described in the BPB table, the "FAT Volume Initialization" section of the Microsoft doc on FAT does provide clear(-ish) instructions on how to pick the various values needed. For FAT16/FAT32 on 512 byte/sector disks, it provides a few lines of code to calculate them. For FAT12, you might need to be more creative since the spot where there clearly should be a table of pre-computed values doesn't seem to have one.
